# Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator even after "as.numeric" fix attempt

Tags: r

> Error "non-numeric..."

in applying calculation to dataframe even after using as.numeric beforehand

I have a dataset with measured data using various Voltage Sensors. You can find excerpt .csv files of the data below
I was provided with the calibration as well as the offset of each sensor. I want to apply those to the measured Voltage Signals with this function.

```
sensor_info <- t(sensor_info)
for (i in 1:nrow(sensor_info)) {
  calibration <- sensor_info[i, "Kalibrierung"]
  if (!is.na(calibration)) {
      sensor <- sensor_info[i, "Sensor"]
      calibration <- as.numeric(calibration)
      pattern <- gsub("[[:space:]/=\\-\\]\\[]", ".", sensor)
      col_index <- as.numeric(grep(pattern, sensor, ignore.case = TRUE))
      offset <- as.numeric(sensor_info[i, "Offset"])
      print(col_index)
      print(typeof(col_index))
      print(calibration)
      print(typeof(calibration))
      print(offset)
      print(typeof(offset))
      for (j in 1:nrow(data)){
         data[j,col_index] <- (data[j,col_index] + offset) * calibration
      }
    }
  }
```

throws error

> Error in data[j, col_index] + offset : non-numeric argument to binary operator

which I dont understand since the print lines return

```
[1] 1
[1] "double"
[1] 699
[1] "double"
[1] 29
[1] "double"
```

What is non-numeric about this?

data.csv: https://pastebin.com/MCdeRpwN
sensor_info.csv: https://pastebin.com/piq4kTe9

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example use `dput(head(sensor_info))` and `dput(head(data))` and the ouput as text. Depending on your expected output there is great potential to shorten your attempt dramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that `data` isn't numeric or immediately coercible to numeric -- it's a set of character vectors containing numbers with comma decimal seperators. To change this to numeric, you can use

```r
data[, 1:33] <- as.data.frame(lapply(data[, 1:33], \(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", x))))
```

Beyond that, your code is unnecessarily complicated and introduces other problems. For one thing, your code doesn't work at all if `sensor_info <- t(sensor_info)` is included. For another:

```r
pattern <- gsub("[[:space:]/=\\-\\]\\[]", ".", sensor)
col_index <- as.numeric(grep(pattern, sensor, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

I think you're trying to match rows from `sensor_info` to corresponding columns in `data`. But if you look at the result of `print(col_index)`, you can see this is just returning `1` on each loop -- so you're just repeatedly transforming your first column while leaving everything else untouched. In any event, it looks like there's a one-to-one correspondence between rows in `sensor_info` and columns in `data`. You can therefore just use the row index from `sensor_data` as the column index for `data` without bothering with the sensor names.

With some further simplifying and vectorizing, you can reduce your loop to

```r
for (i in which(!is.na(sensor_info$Kalibrierung))) {
  data[, i] <- (data[, i] + sensor_info$Offset[[i]]) * sensor_info$Kalibrierung[[i]]
}
```

Resulting in:

```
#> data[1:6, 1:4]
  Zeit..s..CH.1 B1_x_935_699.29.CH.2 B1_y_935_699.24.CH.3 B1_z_935_702.1.CH.4
1          0.00             20768.69             16770.69            712.9512
2          0.01             20769.53             16770.97            712.9512
3          0.02             20769.25             16770.97            713.2320
4          0.03             20769.25             16770.97            713.2320
5          0.04             20768.97             16771.53            713.2320
6          0.05             20769.53             16771.53            713.2320
```